# Components in Jpanel don't obey size/position

Tags: swing

I am having some problems in adding components inside JPanels, in particular I'm adding a JButton and a JLabel, but they don't seem to be respecting the sizes and locations that I gave them.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class test extends JFrame{
    private JPanel panel,panel2;
    private JLabel insMatriz;
    private JButton envMatriz;

    public test(){
        super("Test");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.red);

        panel = new JPanel();
        add(panel,BorderLayout.WEST);
        panel.setBackground(Color.blue);

        panel2 = new JPanel();
        add(panel2,BorderLayout.EAST);
        panel2.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(330,300));
        panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(330,300));


        insMatriz = new JLabel();
        panel.add(insMatriz);
        insMatriz.setSize(new Dimension(50,10));
        insMatriz.setLocation(5,5);
        insMatriz.setText("Insert:");

        envMatriz = new JButton();
        panel2.add(envMatriz);
        envMatriz.setSize(new Dimension(100,50));
        envMatriz.setLocation(5,5);
        envMatriz.setText("Submit");

        setSize(700,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are mixing absolute layout and [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)'s. In Swing you have two options and you have to choose one of them for each component. Trying to do both simultaneously always ends up in troubles:

1. You use absolute layout: this means that you call `setLayout(null)` on that component and you are reponsible for the sizing and positioning of the child components. You have to use setBounds/setSize-setPosition to position and size the child components.
2. You use a LayoutManager (BorderLayout, FlowLayout, GridBagLayout, etc...) and you leave the positioning and sizing to the LayoutManager. To indicate how you want this to be performed, you choose the appropriate LayoutManager, possibly you will provide constraints and you may sometimes (but this should rather be the exception) need to force the minimum/maximum/preferred size.

I would highly recommend to use [LayoutManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) as it will provide cleaner components, better cross-platform experience, respect L&F features and it is more maintainable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should insert another panel into the main panel. Then insert the label into the inner panel.